# Download file with python selenium, correct download directory with firefox driver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, directory, download, geckodriver

i have the following code and its all working correctly except for 1 issue
the file that is downloaded does not go into the specified directory 
what is the issue ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time



url = "THE URL"
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'C://Users/USER/OneDrive/Documents/dest_folder')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")

while True:

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Documents/pycharm/geckodriver.exe',firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    driver.get(url)

    user_field = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email")
    pass_field = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password")
    sign_in = driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit")
    user_field.send_keys(username)
    pass_field.send_keys(password)
    sign_in.click()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(100)
    time.sleep(5)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.yms-button-primary-alt.ng-isolate-scope[csv-header='getCsvHeader'][ng-csv^='fetchData']"))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The script is working well on Python3.9 but I need to know where to adjust the location download file to be saved. This line profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'C://Users/USER/OneDrive/Documents/dest_folder') doesnot work for me even after changing the right folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing your directory to this

```
r'C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\dest_folder'
```

Comment: also doesnot work for me